# How to do file upload with Spring REST API and Test it with RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, resttemplate

I want to,

1) Implement some **REST service method** with **Spring Rest API** for upload some files from my remote web client.

2) Test that with my **RestTemplate** based remote web client.

If any one has some idea please help me. Thanks.

Some of my Spring REST API base methods are as below,

```
@RequestMapping(value="user/create/{userRoleName}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User create(@RequestBody User user, @PathVariable String userRoleName, HttpServletResponse response) { }
```

Some of my remote client's Spring RestTemplate base codes are as below,

```
Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
            vars.put("userRoleName", userRoleName);
            ResponseEntity<User> REcreateUser = restTemplate.postForEntity(IMC_LAB_SKELETON_URL + "/user/create/{userRoleName}", newUser, User.class, vars);
            User createUser = REcreateUser.getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class FileUploadService { 
    @POST
    @Path("/file")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response upload(Attachment attachment,@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
            DataHandler handler = attachment.getDataHandler();
            try {
                InputStream stream = handler.getInputStream();
                MultivaluedMap map = attachment.getHeaders();
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(getFileName(map)));

                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                while ((read = stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                stream.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return Response.ok("file uploaded").build();
    }
```

This can easily be tested with `RestTemplate`.

**Imports:**

- [MediaType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html)
- [Attachment](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/ext/multipart/Attachment.html)
- [MultivaluedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html)

Comment: Hi JSS! Many Thanks for your reply. Can you please mention the list of classes imported for this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Channa: Imports added in the answer now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. Currently I am stuck with test this with RestTemplate, can you please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
 MultiValueMap<String, Object> bodyMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
 //Json Payload as String
 bodyMap.add("payload", payload);
 for (File file : fileArray) {
   bodyMap.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file));
 }
 HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, ?>> entity = new           
 HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, ?>>(bodyMap, headers);
```